# Chrome extension MAX_WRITE quota not replenishing

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I recently have exceeded the number of allowed write operations per hour in my chrome extension and now I receive this message when I attempt to use chrome.storage:

```
Unchecked runtime.lastError while running storage.set:
This request exceeds the MAX_WRITE_OPERATIONS_PER_HOUR quota
```

The problem is that this quota is not replenishing.  It has been almost a full day since this error occurred and it is still throwing this error.  How can I replenish my quota?

Note:
I tried deleting and reloading my unpacked extension and that didn't work.

Comment: Have you tried logging out of your Google account in Chrome?

Comment: just tried it and no luck

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This looks like a long-standing bug: [MAX_WRITE_OPERATIONS_PER_HOUR error despite no write operations during 24 period](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=305498).

Once the quota is reached, a flag for the extension is toggled in-memory and never reset again. Because the quota is [only enforced in memory](https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/src/+/14c3571a07d1ee505a627d3e1658d97cdd8dfc69/extensions/browser/quota_service.cc#60), completely restarting Chrome will lift the quota restriction.

Answer (score 1):

Seems like a bug with Chrome - only way I've been able to get around is moving the unpacked extension to a new directory and loading from there, which generates a new extension id